# How to Find last value of AX and BX in the following code?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
    mov ax, 15
    mov bx, 0Fh
    cmp ax,bx
    jle a1
    mov bx,10
    mov cx,3
    jmp a2
 a1:
    move ax,12
    mov cx,5
 a2:
    dec ax
    inc bx
    loop a2;
```

Comment: `move` isn't an x86 instruction mnemonic.  This won't assemble.  After fixing that, just run it on a real computer or emulator if you can't run it in your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going through the instructions one by one (using [this](https://www.gabrielececchetti.it/Teaching/CalcolatoriElettronici/Docs/i8086_instruction_set.pdf) for example to see what each instruction does)

```
    mov ax, 15     # ax = 15
    mov bx, 0Fh    # bx = 15 (since 0Fh = 15)
    cmp ax,bx      
    jle a1         # if (ax <= bx) jump to a1 -> true
    mov bx,10      # Therefore these not executes
    mov cx,3
    jmp a2
 a1:
    mov ax,12      # ax = 12
    mov cx,5       # cx = 5
 a2:
    dec ax         # ax = ax - 1
    inc bx         # bx = bx + 1
    loop a2;       # cx = cx - 1 AND if (cx != 0) then jump to a2. Since cx is 5 when
                   # reaching here therefore looping 4 times which means overall the
                   # effect is ax = ax - 4 = 12 - 4 = 8 and bx = bx + 4 = 15 + 4 = 19
```

AX will be 8 and BX will be 19 after executing this code.

Corrected based @ecm 's eagle eyes observation.

Comment: `jle` jumps if the comparison is equal (as well as if `ax` is lesser than `bx` in signed comparison). So it does jump in this example, contrary to your comment.

Comment: jump a1 or a2 ?

Comment: @KirigayaKazuto a1

Comment: @Eraklon cx 5 ? agians 4?